# Extreme longevity read-only flash storage

Tags: usb, data-storage, flash-drive

I'm looking for a flash storage solution that combines highest achievable read durability with the lowest price. Low speeds and relatively small capacity (1 GB minimum) are acceptable. I'm looking to encase these drives myself, so the appearance is irrelevant and the more barebones they are, the better.

In my research, I've found that the main factor that affects life expectancy of flash digital storage is writes (or, rather, erases). Luckily, for my use case, I expect to write **once** though read frequently.

[These "Walletsticks"](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Chic-WalletStick-USB-Flash-Drive-With_60636654070.html) is closest thing I was able to find, but I'm wondering whether it's possible to do better? The advertised data retention time on these is 10 years, whereas I'm hoping to extend that even further.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by “embed [...] into [...] physical goods” in a context where the example you give is an USB flash drive. Are you looking for a flash drive, or rather an integrated circuit? If the former, what about the chips used to store BIOS in motherboards or other hardware, especially server grade hardware with life expectancy bigger than ten years? Also, you should be more precise about “low speeds” and “small capacity.” For some people, small capacity is anything less than 1 GB. For others, it's 4 KB.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't sufficiently clear. I *am* after a "flash drive", rather than a circuit, though a very barebones one. I want to *encase* it, rather than "embed". It does need to be USB (or something similar) to be easily pluggable and readable with a conventional computer.